# Cucumber tests not executing when running maven test

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, pom.xml

I have a cucumber project. When I right click on the RunnerTest class and "Run "RunnerTest" all the features from the feature file starts running. All tests pass.

My RunnerTest.class

```
   import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = {"classpath:foo.feature"},
glue = "com.foo.foobar.StepDefinitions",
plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json"},
monochrome = true,
strict = true
//,dryRun = true
)

@Log4j2
public class RunnerTest {}
```

But when I try to run mvn test or mvn clean install features are not running.
This is the output.

---

### T E S T S

Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@515f550a
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.895 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

These are my POM dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!--<dependency>-->
  <!--<groupId>junit</groupId>-->
  <!--<artifactId>junit</artifactId>-->
  <!--<version>4.12</version>-->
<!--</dependency>-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.14.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have tried to add mvn surefire plugin and including my RunnerTest Class there.

```
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.4</version>
     <configuration>
       <includes>
       <include>RunnerTest.java</include>
       </includes>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

But that does not work either

Comment: Your class is importing JUnit annotations (`@RunWith`) whereas your Maven output says it's trying to use TestNG

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Thanks. Can you kindly let me know how to overcome this issue? I need my TestNG dependency as well because I am using testNG assertions

Comment: I have limited experience with Cucumber and no experience with TestNG so the best I can do is ask Google. What I've found suggests that you should remove the `@RunWith` annotation and let the test class extend `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` (source: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/testng )

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke   Ah Thanks. But my expectation is to run it with Junit and not TestNG. Just for the time being I commented very TestNG dependency and tried to run again. Still maven tries to execute using TestNG. Dunno why. I'm also googling . Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Known Issue :**  If you keep Junit & TestNG both dependencies in parallel, Then TestNG dependency causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class.

**Solution :** There could be multiple way of handling this like we can define 2 execution, each for TestNG & JUnit and disable one as per your need.

**Can you please try with this :** Please remove any direct/indirect TestNG dependency.

org.testng
    testng
    6.14.3
    test

And try to add below one -

io.cucumber
    cucumber-testng
    3.0.0

**Also, I would suggest you one more thing** to keep your pom.xml clean.

**Key Point :**

- We shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome.

### Cucumber Execution via JUnit

You shall remove cucumber-core, cucumber-java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-jvm-deps, gherkin as these are transitive dependencies which would get added by Maven when you add below direct (main) dependencies. Just add below 2 and one for testng shared above.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I removed all the other dependencies as you asked. But when I ran it was running with TestNG again. So i deleted the cucumber-testNG dependency as well. Then it started picking up the Junit wrapper Sclass. o I guess I cant keep any testNG dependencies at all.